# Crear un validador de fechas java

Tags: java

el caso es que tengo que hacer un ejercicio de crear un validador de fechas que tenga la fecha en un formato concreto, ej: 12-05-2001. Tiene que llevar ese formato y aparte te tiene que decir el dia que era esa fecha, además tiene que mostrar la fecha de años bisiestos. He tirado de varios ejemplos y no me son validos ya que no puedo utilizar la libreria Simpledateformat, ni los arrays ni los
try-catch. Mi problema viene en como crear lo que es el validador de la fecha con ese formato en específico y que sea valida.

EDIT: Pongo el código de lo que intento hacer.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ComprobadorFechas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce la fecha(dd/mm/yyyy):  ");
        validarFecha(sc.next());
    }
    public static boolean validarFecha( String fecha) {

    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anyo;
    dia = Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(0,2));
    mes = Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(4,5));
    anyo = Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(6,fecha.length()));

    if (anyo>=1900 && anyo<=9999)
    {
        switch (mes)
        {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            System.out.println("Estos meses tienen 31 dias");
        break;

        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            System.out.println("Estos meses tienen 30 dias ");
        break;
        case 2:
             if ((anyo % 4 == 0 && anyo % 100 != 0) || (anyo % 400 == 0)) 
             {
                System.out.println("El año es bisisesto");
                    if (mes>=1 && mes<=28)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Febrero cae bisiesto, tiene de 1 a 28 dias");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Febrero no es bisiesto, tiene de 1 a 29 dias");
                    }
             }
        break;  

        }

    }




    return false;


    }

}
```

Las 3 dudas que tengo son:

1: El programa tiene un error, el formato de la fecha tiene que ser ej 11/07/2000 y solo estar formado de numeros, al poner algo como: a1/e3/yyyy me salta un error de java, necesito que solo me coja los numeros.

2: Otro problema que tengo es el siguiente: Tengo que poner la fecha con "/" de lo contrario la fecha es incorrecta osea no puedo poner cosas como estas: 1/1/01 o 01-04-2000 tiene que estar formado por dd/mm/yyyy y no puedo utilizar librerias.

3: El ultimo problema es, al comprobar que el año es bisiesto ¿Como hago para que cuando sea febrero no bisiesto los dias valgan de 1 a 29 y los bisiestos de 1 al 28 en el switch?.

Me he intentado explicar todo lo posible. Lo siento por la confusión del tema.

Comment: Primero bienvenido a StackOverflow, te pediría que muestres el código ya que de normal este tipos de preguntas se muestran como si deseas que se te realice el código en vez de preguntar por un fallo o duda en concreto.

Comment: Gracias, por contestar, no tengo un error en código como para mostrarlo, mi pregunta era mas sobre conocimiento de como podía introducir la fecha en un formato tal que así: (dd/mm/yyyy) sin la libreria SimpleDate y sin  que tuviera que introducir por separado el dia, luego y mes y luego el año. Perdón por el post pero soy nuevo en el foro y no sabía como funcionaba. Ademas soy un poco dummie en esto.

Comment: ¿Y según me indicas no puedes usar SimpleDateFormat, y que tampoco sea sin introducir cada celda por separado sino todo junto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se si es lo que buscas pero he intentado hacer un código "cercano" a lo que pides por las limitaciones que has indicado, he usado un Date pero se considera `deprecated`, que significa que puede dar problemas (y los da) o que existe una alternativa mejor (por ejemplo `SimpleDateFormat`). Básicamente pide al usuario y le "obliga" a escribir en un formato de dd/mm/yyyy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Indicar fecha en este formato ---> dd/mm/yyyy: ");
    String formi = br.readLine();

    Date Changdate=new Date(formi);
    System.out.println(Changdate);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Error, indicar en este formato: 01/01/2001");
    }
```

En caso de que busques algo mas especifico o complejo que esto indícalo en tu pregunta y muestra el código que intentas realizar.